# The Tableau server is running on the EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, tableau-api

I have a Tableau server running on EC2 instance followed steps from this documentation

[Tableau Server & Amazon AWS - Installation Walkthrough](http://community.tableausoftware.com/thread/135464)

What additional information or what things i require to connect to that tableau server from a remote desktop?
please somebody guide me on this!

I am not able to understand that how would a remote computer connect to the tableau server running on EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

Steps 3 and 4 involve creating a static EIP address and then assigning that to your AWS instance. This static EIP address is the one you use to access your Tableau Server from a remote computer.